# DIV Inside jQueryUI Dialog is overflowed after multiple resizes to the dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hello and thank you all for the quality answers that I always found here...

I have a jQueryUI dialog with a DIV inside...

This div is set to fill the dialog space:

```
div.dialog-contents {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
}
```

When I start resizing the dialog (horizontal or vertical) it slowly starts to shrink or enlarge beyond the dialog boundaries!!!... this is weird...

When I inspect the element with debugging tools I notice this:

In the outer div (the div in wich the dialog is created) the size is computed this way:
`width: 294.960000038147px;`

But in the inner div (the one set to fill space) it is rounded, so it starts to be different pixels as I resize the dialog
`width: 248px;`

I dont know what I'm doing wrong, should I use some other setting to accomplish this?

I Just want my internal div to be always 100% width and 100% height (and staying inside dialog boundaries)

Here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/e9QjD/2/

Try to resize several times the dialog to see the behaviour

Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems like something is missing from your JSFiddle. One thing that's happened to me with it is I didn't realize you need to click Update, if you've made edits after Share-ing. Does that help?

Comment: works fine for me in chrome and firefox

Comment: Really it worked fine for you?? Did you try to resize several times (like 8 or 10) ?

Comment: @Juanchi can I get some feeback on my answer?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a possible work around.

I did see there was an issue with the height of your `window-session-editor` the height keeps increasing slightly relative to the modal on each re-size.  I could not see an issue with the width changing.  I'm not sure why this is happening but a work around would be to re-adjust the height after every re-size.

```
$(function () {   
    $("#window-session_editor").dialog({
        resizeStop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).height($(this).parent().height()-$(this).prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar').height()-34);
        }    
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e9QjD/3/

**Update addressing width**

```
$(function () {   
    $("#window-session_editor").dialog({
        resizeStop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).height($(this).parent().height()-$(this).prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar').height()-34);
            $(this).width($(this).prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar').width()+2);
        }    
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e9QjD/4/

Comment: Hi Trevor, thank you for your workaround, but it seems that the width is still shrinking on the internal div, I don't know why, but if you start resizing it starts shrinking... I'm using Chrome on Windows but also tested on firefox...

Comment: @Juanchi hmm I didn't see that the width was shrinking, I'm using chrome on windows as well.  I'll take another look.  Okay now I see it.  I'll get an update.

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you very much @Trevor, don't you think this behaviour is like a bug on jQueryUI's dialog??

Comment: @Juanchi I think you are probably right..  You could probably report it and include the example you have in this question.  Please mark this answer as accepted it resolved your question.  (Look for the `checkmark` to the left of the question and click it.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much @Trevor, can you help me with one last thing in your workaround ?, the -34 on height represents the height of the titlebar right? and I think the +2 on the width represents the padding, is there any way that we can make this more generic, like accesing that value from the dom instead of setting it directly ?

Comment: @Juanchi well yes the +2 represents the padding I believe if you want to get rid of the +2 you could do `$(this).innerWidth($(this).prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar').outerWidth());` Now on the height I already accounted for the height of the title bar and I still was `34` off.  I have not figured out why that is. I'm sure there is someway to do it if I were to experiment with inner and outer widths.. If I have time later i'll try to find a way to do it..  Feel free to experiment as well and post the answer here if you find something.